# Set Docker volumes size quota within docker-compose driver opts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am testing with docker-compose and volumes storage quotas.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` I have **working** for now:
[image: docker-compose.yml]
Which is pretty much a simple Apache, with PHP and an upload php file.

What I am unable to find is to make the volume be "like the others", I just want to add the quota line, something like this:

```
volumes:
    storage1:
        driver_opts:
            o: 'size=100000,uid=1000'

    storage2:
        driver_opts:
            o: 'size=1g'

    storage3:
        driver_opts:
            o: 'size=100m'
    ...
```

...but of course this does not work, I `need to specify the device`, which I do not know what the default is, and if I need anything else.

Like I said, I just want "default" behaviour with the size quota working, and I though I could achieve this by re-setting the default values in the mandatory `driver_opts` parameters. So, how could I achieve that?
(If there is a better way, please tell me.)

*System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 / Docker 18.09*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? What other volumes are you intending to mimic in your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @lolsky Thanks for answer. I do not think I really understand you. In this case I want to test with a single volume, but in other cases the amount could be higher. I will edit the question for better clarity.